# Hartshorne III.10.4

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

[image]

In order to apply II.8.9, we need $\dim_kM\otimes_{A}k=\dim_KM\otimes_AK$ to show $M$ is free, where $A$ is a local integral domain, but by the result of generic and closed points, we only have $\dim_k(\Omega_{X/Y})_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}k=\dim_{K(X)}(\Omega_{X/Y})_{\xi}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}}K(X)$, where $x$ is the closed point and $\xi$ is the generic point (thus $k(x)=k,k(\xi)=K(X)$ and $\Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)=(\Omega_{X/Y})_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k$). 
So we don't have the same local ring $A$ and $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x\not=(\Omega_{X/Y})_\xi$ in general. Moreover, I think we want $M$ to be the $\Omega_{X/Y}(U)$ instead of the stalk. I wonder how to apply the  II.8.9 correctly?

Comment: You have a probable typo in your last paragraph (first line): "is coherent of sheaf $n$?"

Comment: @KReiser fixed, thank you

Comment: @KReiser actually, in order to apply II.8.9, we need $\dim_kM\otimes_{A}k=\dim_KM\otimes_AK$ to show $M$ is free, where $A$ is a local integral domain, but by the result of generic and closed points, we only have $\dim_k(\Omega_{X/Y})_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}k=\dim_{K(X)}(\Omega_{X/Y})_{\xi}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}}K(X)$. Can you tell me how to apply?

Comment: This last comment reads as kind of unpleasantly demanding to me - I was already a fair amount of the way through writing you an answer addressing your question, and now I'm not sure if I want to finish at this time. Anyways, all of this can be dealt with rather easily through the strategies from the previous answers I've given you over the past couple days plus reading the text.

Comment: @KReiser Ok, I will keep working on that. I feel appreciated for your answers and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us recall the text of Lemma II.8.9:

> **Lemma II.8.9**: Let $A$ be noetherian local domain, with residue field $k$ and quotient field $K$. If $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module and if $\dim_k M\otimes_A k=\dim_K M\otimes_A K=R$, then $M$ is free of rank $r$.
>
> **Proof**: Since $\dim_k M\otimes_A k=r$, Nakayama's lemma tells us that $M$ can be generated by $r$ elements. So there is a surjective map $\varphi:A^r\to M$. Let $R$ be its kernel. Then we obtain an exact sequence $$ 0\to R\otimes_A K\to K^r\to M\otimes_A K\to 0,$$ and since $\dim_K M\otimes_A K=r$, we see that $R\otimes_A K=0$. But $R$ is torsion-free, so $R=0$, and $M$ is isomorphic to $A^r$.

A couple reminders: we have the exact sequence because the functor $-\otimes_A K$ is exact, because it's the same as localizing at $(0)$ and localization is exact. $R$ is torsion-free because any torsion would have to be $\mathfrak{m}$-torsion, but this would be killed by tensoring with $k$, implying that $\dim_k M\otimes_A k < r$.

To apply this in our situation, we immediately notice that we may reduce to the case of $X$ affine integral, say $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$. Then $\Omega_{X/Y}$, being a coherent sheaf on $X$, is of the form $\widetilde{F}$ for a finitely-generated $R$-module $F$. Now for a closed point $x\in X$ and the generic point $\zeta\in X$, $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x=F_x$ and $(\Omega_{X/Y})_\zeta = F_{(0)}$ by the properties of stalks of quasi-coherent sheaves on affine schemes. This puts us in the situation of II.8.9 by taking $A=R_x$, $M=F_x$, $k=k(x)$, $K=Frac(R)$, and $r=n$. The claim that $\dim_{k(x)} \Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)=n$ translates to $\dim_k M\otimes_A k=r$, so we get a surjection $A^r\to M$ and thus an exact sequence of the form $$0\to R \to A^r\to M\to 0$$ as in the proof. Tensoring with $K$ (aka localizing at $(0)$) preserves exactness, and the middle term becomes $K^r$, which implies $\dim_K M\otimes_A K\leq r$. On the other hand, the statement that $\dim_{k(\zeta)} \Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(\zeta) \geq n$ is equivalent to $\dim_K M\otimes_A K\geq r$, which means that $\dim_K M\otimes_A K= r$. Now we can apply the conclusion of II.8.9 to see that $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x$ is free of rank $n$.

By exercise II.5.7(a), cited in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640694/question-of-hartshorne-ii8-15), this implies that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $n$, and we are done.

The two key ideas in this proof are some foundational results on stalks for quasicoherent sheaves over affines, and some algebra with local rings. Your recent questions have shown some lack of understanding of the first topic - I would recommend you take another look at what's going on there, because these statements are necessary background knowledge to get stuff done in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion. I will spend time on the quasicoherent sheaves.

Comment: It seems that you assume $\Omega_{X/Y,x}=F_x\cong F_y\cong M$ for any $x,y\in X$, but I don't think $\Omega_{X/Y,x}\cong \Omega_{X/Y,y}$ in general.

Comment: To be more precise,  I think $\Omega_{X/Y,\zeta}$ might not be $\cong\Omega_{X/Y,x}$ for any $x$.

Comment: I do not assume $\Omega_{X/Y,x}\cong\Omega_{X/Y,y}$ for any distinct points $x,y$ and I do not understand what gave you that idea. All that's going on here is some basic stuff about localization: if we have two prime ideals $I\subset J\subset R$, then $(R_J)_{I_J}=R_I$. This means that without saying anything about whether $\Omega_{X/Y,x}\cong\Omega_{X/Y,y}$, we know that $\Omega_{X/Y,\zeta}$ is a localization of $\Omega_{X/Y,x}$ for any point $x\in X$.

Comment: Your tensors in the second half of that don't make sense - $M$ is not a $K$-module, so you cannot even form the tensor product $M\otimes_KK$. This is just the basics of quasicoherent sheaves again: we are working with $\Omega_{X/Y}$ coherent over an affine scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$, so it is $\widetilde{F}$ for some $R$-module $F$. Then $\Omega_{X/Y,\zeta}=F_{(0)}$, and by my previous comment, $(F_{p})_{(0)}=F_{(0)}$ for any prime $p\subset R$, so $\Omega_{X/Y,x}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(\zeta)=\Omega_{X/Y,\zeta}$.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot $M\otimes _AK\cong M_{(0)}$  so I was confused. Thanks again